# How to write an Image without running out of memory in Java?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, bufferedimage, graphics2d

```
final BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(3500, 2480, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED);
final Graphics2D g2D = img.createGraphics();
g2D.setBackground(Color.white);
g2D.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
```

(full code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929869/how-to-draw-a-text-image-for-printing-in-java) question).

This code results in a Java Heap Space exception although I've set the jvm attribute to 3GB. Could that be the problem?

Anyway isn't it possible to draw the image with less memory? I'm after an A4-size BMP for printing, only with text. Most of the time it's black-and-white only, while at some times I'll need to use blue, pink, and gray too.

Comment: as the linked question of yours is no longer available (at least not for me?) could you provide the full code here?

Answer (score 0):

There is something very fishy about the facts stated in your question.  Unless I'm mistakened, that `BufferedImage` uses 1 byte per pixel, and therefore `3500 x 2480` bytes ... around 10Mbytes.  But you claim to have set the heap size to 3Gbytes.

What JVM options did you actually use?

Comment: Env.MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024M (1GB now)

Comment: That's the setting for the maven build.  What do you use when you run your application?

Comment: It's the settings for: install nbm:run-platform , which is how I run it.

Comment: I think you are actually setting the options for the JVM that runs maven NOT the child JVM that runs your application.

Comment: I think you to use the "additionalArguments" parameters as described here: http://mojo.codehaus.org/nbm-maven-plugin/run-platform-mojo.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem emerged moving to maven 3, now that I think of it. Also, the edition executing from a .jnlp setting the memory works. Where can I learn more about the maven jvm and child?

Comment: I imagine this is specific to the plugin you are using.  Try reading the documentation for the nbm plugin (e.g. the link above!), and if that fails check the mailing lists or Google it.

Comment: have found where to set it. I've posted the way to at http://forums.netbeans.org/topic32681.html